# Error when using pandas dataframe in R cell, in rpy2, Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, r, pandas, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I want to use `ggplot2` within `Jupyter Notebook`. However, when I try to make an R magic cell and introduce a variable, I get an error.

Here is the code (one paragraph indicates one cell):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import rpy2

%matplotlib inline
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R
library(ggplot2)

data = pd.read_csv('train_titanic.csv')

%%R -i data -w 900 -h 480 -u px
```

With this last cell, I get the following error (incl traceback):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py in py2rpy_pandasdataframe(obj)
     54         try:
---> 55             od[name] = conversion.py2rpy(values)
     56         except Exception as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py in py2rpy_pandasseries(obj)
    125             if type(x) is not homogeneous_type:
--> 126                 raise ValueError('Series can only be of one type, or None.')
    127         # TODO: Could this be merged with obj.type.name == 'O' case above ?

ValueError: Series can only be of one type, or None.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in from_object(cls, obj)
    367         try:
--> 368             mv = memoryview(obj)
    369             res = cls.from_memoryview(mv)

TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-75e210679e4a> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '-i data -w 900 -h 480 -u px', '\n\n')

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

</home/morgan/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-130> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    721                         raise NameError("name '%s' is not defined" % input)
    722                 with localconverter(converter) as cv:
--> 723                     ro.r.assign(input, val)
    724 
    725         tmpd = self.setup_graphics(args)

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    190                 kwargs[r_k] = v
    191         return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
--> 192                 .__call__(*args, **kwargs))
    193 
    194 

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    111 
    112     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 113         new_args = [conversion.py2rpy(a) for a in args]
    114         new_kwargs = {}
    115         for k, v in kwargs.items():

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    111 
    112     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 113         new_args = [conversion.py2rpy(a) for a in args]
    114         new_kwargs = {}
    115         for k, v in kwargs.items():

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py in py2rpy_pandasdataframe(obj)
     59                           'The error is: %s'
     60                           % (name, str(e)))
---> 61             od[name] = StrVector(values)
     62 
     63     return DataFrame(od)

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py in __init__(self, obj)
    382 
    383     def __init__(self, obj):
--> 384         super().__init__(obj)
    385         self._add_rops()
    386 

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in __init__(self, obj)
    286             super().__init__(obj)
    287         elif isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Sized):
--> 288             super().__init__(type(self).from_object(obj).__sexp__)
    289         else:
    290             raise TypeError('The constructor must be called '

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in from_object(cls, obj)
    370         except (TypeError, ValueError):
    371             try:
--> 372                 res = cls.from_iterable(obj)
    373             except ValueError:
    374                 msg = ('The class methods from_memoryview() and '

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _(*args, **kwargs)
     26 def _cdata_res_to_rinterface(function):
     27     def _(*args, **kwargs):
---> 28         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
     29         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType
     30         return _cdata_to_rinterface(cdata)

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in from_iterable(cls, iterable, populate_func)
    317             if populate_func is None:
    318                 cls._populate_r_vector(iterable,
--> 319                                        r_vector)
    320             else:
    321                 populate_func(iterable, r_vector)

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in _populate_r_vector(cls, iterable, r_vector)
    300                                   r_vector,
    301                                   cls._R_SET_VECTOR_ELT,
--> 302                                   cls._CAST_IN)
    303 
    304     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in _populate_r_vector(iterable, r_vector, set_elt, cast_value)
    237 def _populate_r_vector(iterable, r_vector, set_elt, cast_value):
    238     for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
--> 239         set_elt(r_vector, i, cast_value(v))
    240 
    241 

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py in _as_charsxp_cdata(x)
    430         return x.__sexp__._cdata
    431     else:
--> 432         return conversion._str_to_charsxp(x)
    433 
    434 

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _str_to_charsxp(val)
    118         s = rlib.R_NaString
    119     else:
--> 120         cchar = _str_to_cchar(val)
    121         s = rlib.Rf_mkCharCE(cchar, _CE_UTF8)
    122     return s

~/anaconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _str_to_cchar(s, encoding)
     97 def _str_to_cchar(s, encoding: str = 'utf-8'):
     98     # TODO: use isStrinb and installTrChar
---> 99     b = s.encode(encoding)
    100     return ffi.new('char[]', b)
    101 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So I find that it is not possible to even start an R magic cell while importing my pandas dataframe object. However, I have tried creating R vectors inside the cell, and find I can plot these using `ggplot2` with no issues.

I am using `Python 3.7.6`, `rpy2 3.1.0`, `jupyter-notebook 6.0.3`and am using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: What is in `train_titanic.csv`?

Comment: I think that you do not need `from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri` and `pandas2ri.activate()` if using rpy2 magics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely with one (or more) columns having more than one type - therefore it is impossible to transfer the data into an R vector (which can hold only one data type). The traceback may be overwhelming, but here is the relevant part:

```
ValueError: Series can only be of one type, or None.
```

Which column it is? Difficult to say without looking at the dataset that you load, but my general solution is to check the types in the columns:

```
types = data.applymap(type).apply(set)
types[types.apply(len) > 1]
```

Anything returned by the snippet above would be a candidate culprit. There are many different ways of dealing with the problem, depending on the exact nature of the data. Workarounds that I frequently use include:

- calling `data = data.infer_objects()` - helps if the pandas did not catch up with a dtype change and still stores the data with (suboptimal) Python objects
- filling `NaN` with an empty string or a string constant if you have missing values in a string column (e.g. `str_columns = str_columns.fillna('')`)
- `dates.apply(pd.to_datetime, axis=1)` if you have `datetime` objects but the dtype is object
- using `df.applymap(lambda x: datetime.combine(x, datetime.min.time()) if not isinstance(x, datetime) else x)` if you have a mixture of `date` and `datetime` objects

In some vary rare cases pandas stores the data differently than expected by rpy2 (following certain manipulations); then writing the dataframe down to a csv file and reading it from the disk again helps - but this is likely not what you are facing here, as you start from a newly read dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed there might be an even simpler reason for the problem. For some reason, `pandas2ri` requires you to call `pandas2ri.activate()`after importing it. This solved the problem for me.